# UITabbarViewController: Use StoryboardReferences

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

To have each tab content in it's own Storyboar I use storyboard references and configure the title and image in my viewcontroller.

[image]

I set the image and the title inside the viewDidLoad method in each viewcontroller. This has the problem that the TabbarItem is not displayed until I tab it, beacause the viewcontrollers are lazy loaded an not when the tabbbarController is loaded.

How can I improve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take `UINavigationController` before your `UIViewController`'s reference and make root view of that `UINavigationController`. By this way it will give you a tabbar item to configure in `UINavigationController` in storyboard.

[image]